# Change DNS on all requests

Tags: android, kotlin, dns, interceptor

I need to change DNS on all Android requests. How to get it done?

I found [this](https://developpaper.com/android-network-optimization-use-http-dns-to-optimize-dns-from-principle-to-okhttp-integration/):

```
class HTTPDNSInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val originRequest = chain.request()
        val httpUrl = originRequest.url()

        val url = httpUrl.toString()
        val host = httpUrl.host()

        val hostIP = HttpDNS.getIpByHost(host)
        val builder = originRequest.newBuilder()

        if (hostIP != null) {
            builder.url(HttpDNS.getIpUrl(url, host, hostIP))
            builder.header("host", hostIP)
        }
        val newRequest = builder.build()
        val newResponse = chain.proceed(newRequest)
        return newResponse
    }
}
```

But, I don't have all the helper classes and I have not found any library where I can explicitly set certain DNS. Even if there is a way to dynamically check valid DNS and setting any working, would be great too.

Comment: What helper classes are you looking for? Have you tried using okhttp, as the article says?

Comment: `HttpDNS`. I think the article might be incomplete. How should I implement it? With the .dns(myDns)?

Comment: I don't know much about this topic, but I would look at https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp-dnsoverhttps/okhttp3.dnsoverhttps/ Are you trying to change what DNS is used by the Android system, so that it will affect all apps? Or just to change the DNS used by your app?